# I want to write to a file from am IRandomAccessStream

Tags: c#, uwp

Here is my code:

```
                    using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
                    {
                        //Irrelevant
                        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                        await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);
                        myImage.Source = bitmapImage;

                        //Relevant again
                        Windows.Storage.StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
                        StorageFolder fol = await localFolder.GetFolderAsync("this");
                        StorageFile canvasFile = await fol.CreateFileAsync("background.png", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

                        using (var entryStream = await canvasFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
                        {
                            await fileStream.AsStreamForRead().CopyToAsync(entryStream);
                        }
                    }
```

The file is created, but has a size of 0 bits and is quite empty. Any ideas what might be going wrong here?

Comment: Why did you post code that "irrelevant"? Please read [MCVE] guidance on posting code. Note that you are responsible for verification that code you believe is actually relevant to the question indeed demonstrates the problem (which is likely not be the case here).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to write `IRandomAccessStream` to a file, you need to convert `IRandomAccessStream` into `IInputStream` and then use `DataReader` to get the buffer from  `IInputStream`. For more detail, you could refer the below code.

```
using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
{
    Windows.Storage.StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    StorageFolder fol = await localFolder.CreateFolderAsync("this", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
    StorageFile canvasFile = await fol.CreateFileAsync("background.png", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    using (var reader = new DataReader(fileStream.GetInputStreamAt(0)))
    {
        await reader.LoadAsync((uint)fileStream.Size);
        var buffer = new byte[(int)fileStream.Size];
        reader.ReadBytes(buffer);
        await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(canvasFile, buffer);
    }
}
```